# Xamarin Android XML Errors for Resource Localization after updating so many packages

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build a Xamarin app locally after updating so many packages.
Build is trying to create localized versions of the resources but fail.
I don't use localized versions of the resources.

Error like:

```
values.xml "error APT2254: xml parser error: no element found"
values.xml "error APT2261: file failed to compile"
```

Visual Studio Version 16.9.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many tests, I deleted the "obj" folder, clean solution, rebuild and all went well.